What is the figure of speech scheme name for "X and Y, Y and X"?
I would like to properly classify a figure of speech that can be generalized as "X and Y, Y and X". Here is a specific example randomly generated by my imagination: "Honey and berries, berries and honey. This is what every respectable bear values the most, my friend!".
On the top level, I know it is a scheme, not a trope. But when I am looking at the list of figure of speech schemes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech#Schemes), I can't seem to find a good match.
Also, a related question: does anyone know a historical origin of this scheme and especially is any historical villains have tarnished it by using it? I doubt that I am an original inventor of this scheme and it definitely feels like I have heard it somewhere before.

@curiousdannii Why was this moved away from Linguistics.SE?!? You have a ton of questions over there that ask for the name of a figure of speech. Also, it was already correctly answered on your site. What further answers do you expect?

I did not move it, I have no idea who did it.

And as far as "correctly answered" is concerned, I still have my doubts as to whether antimetabole is the best match. It is close, but again, "X and Y, Y and X" lacks the opposition typically found in the structure of the antimetabole.

Precisely "changing the relationship between the terms" does NOT happen in the phrase "Honey and berries, berries and honey. This is what every respectable bear values the most, my friend!" Here reversal of the order re-emphasizes that honey and berries, like nothing else, go together on the bear's menu.

The figure of speech is called antimetabole which itself is a special form of chiasmus.

An antimetabole needs not be antithetical.
The German Historisches Wörterbuch der Rhetorik Online [Historical Dictionary of Rhetoric Online] defines the antimetabole as (Google translation):

a special form of thought reversal: a thought (usually a two-part sentence or two concepts) is repeated, whereby the two parts are swapped in the repetition. ... The A. is usually used as an effective form of antithesis. However, it can not only reverse the underlying thought, but also intensify it, generalize it, exaggerate it, etc. An example of a non-antithetical form of A., a clever play on words, is provided by Cicero in ‹De oratore›: «iuris peritorum eloquentissimus, eloquentium iuris peritissimus» (the greatest orator among lawyers, the greatest lawyer among orators).

The Oxford English Dictionary (s.v. antimetabole) provides another non-antithetical example, where both phrases express the same thought (that poetry is more expressive than painting):

Painting is mute poetry; poetry is eloquent painting.

